# SharePoint 2010 wrong encoding when webtemplate is a farm feature

Tags: xml

i create a new SharePoint Site with a sitepage template. My Problem is, the columnnames of my library has a wrong coding.

My schema.xml has a encoding UTF-8 and the XML file () too.

e.g. PrÃ¼fer  is wrong, right is Prüfer

sorry for my english.

Update: When i deploy the template as sandbox solution the encoding is correct.
When the template deploy as farmsolution the encoding is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that as farm solution get deployed to the filesystem, the file's encoding is screwed up when it is written to the file system. Could you try encoding the character as [ISO-8859-1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) character:

```
&#252;
```